# Why only densely defined operators can have an adjoint operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Why is it impossible or making no sense to define an adjoint operator for a non-densely defined operator?

Answer (score 4):

The adjoint is defined as

$$
\langle T^\ast u, v\rangle = \langle u, Tv\rangle.
$$

This only defines $T^\ast u$ **uniquely** if the set of all $v$, for which this equation makes sense is dense.

But this means that $T$ has to be densely defined.

Comment: Why does densely defined implies that $T^*v$ is unique when it exists?